# JavaScript function parameter naming conventions

Tags: javascript, parameter-passing, naming

Is it common to use the accepted parameter naming conventions for a JavaScript function?  For example:

```
function MyFunction(nParam1, tParam2, oParam3) {..}
```

where `nParam1` is a number, `tParam2` is text, and `oParam3` is an object

It makes sense to do this, but there is a lot of code I still see that does not use this naming convention.

Comment: Hungarian notation is horrible. Don't use it.

Comment: This question is a little too vague. The one answer I can think of is "maybe doing this makes less sense than you think." For instance, it's common in jQuery for a parameter to take a whole bunch of "types" of values.

Comment: I'm also in favour of just using documentation instead of type-Hungarian. Or, if you want manifest typing, consider something like TypeScript which probably has a notion of types closer to actual JS practice than C where Hungarian stems from.

Comment: Is sObject a string if tObject is text?  I personally prefer price, description, addressObject or similar

Comment: (That said, I admit to using Hungarian/acronyms to encode metadata that describes the purpose of / relationship between variables. I.e. `items` will be an array, and `nItems` would be a count of items. Or `txtName` to refer to a text input box, and `lblName` for the label for it.)

Comment: The only convention I follow is to try to make my names as semantically clear as possible.  For example, `obj` or `object` makes a lot more sense to me than `oParam3`. Or, even better, use a more descriptive name.  After all, we should strive to make code as clear and legible as possible.

And please, don't start your function name with uppercase if it's not a constructor!

Comment: If you want to identify type of the parameters use JsDoc and JsDuck. Examples: https://github.com/senchalabs/jsduck/wiki/@param That information does not belong into the name of the variable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is it common to use the accepted parameter naming conventions for a JavaScript function?

I don't know what you mean by "...the accepted parameter naming conventions..." (I've seen at least half a dozen argument naming conventions in various languages and environments, none "accepted" universally)...

...But the answer is no, there is no broadly-used naming convention for function arguments in JavaScript — unless you consider just using plain names (e.g., without any Hungarian-esque prefixes and such) a convention. Plain names is the overwhelmingly most common thing I see. Specifically, plain names that start with a lower-case letter. Once you get past that, there's more variety. `camelCase` is common, but so is `snake_case`.

The closest things I see in the wild in terms of conventions are:

1. Initially-capped mixed-case, such as `Date` or `Foo`, is pretty much reserved for constructor functions.
2. `ALL_CAPS` is typically used only for things that are treated like constants.
3. Everything else seems to start with lower case, and be either `camelCase` or `underscore_separated`. No clear-cut consensus on that, although I think `camelCase` has an edge, probably because JavaScript itself uses it (`toLowerCase`, etc.).